# Python Numpy. Manipulating with 2 matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have 2 CSV files with the same size. Values are `1`s and `0`s.

I need to loop over 2 files (matrices) and create a new matrix using the following logic:

```
if matrix A value = 1 and matrix B value = 1 
  then 
      result value is 0, 

if 1 and 0 
  then 
      0, 

if 0 and 0 
  then 
      0.

A = [
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
]
B = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0]
]
=>
C = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1]
]
```

I know that Numpy is used to loop and manipulate with matrices and arrays, but I stuck to find how to do it in a proper way.

Comment: According to your logic: "if matrix A value = 1 and matrix B value = 1 then result value is 0, if 1 and 0 then 0, if 0 and 0 then 0.", all values are 0...... Please correct your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get your desired output, but I think the logic you described was not quite what you meant. This outputs an array of `1` where your matrices are different from one another, and `0` where they are alike.

```
A = np.array([
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
])

B = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0]])


C = (A != B).astype('int')

array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```